# First point of gradient change in matlab

Tags: matlab, average, gradient

I'm looking to automate the finding of a location on a plot.
[this is the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U8Lv.jpg)

I want my code to automatically find the point where the plot smoothes out. The point that is highlighted in the plot. I did this by hand with the selector tool, but I need to do it for many different plots, so selecting them each by hand would take too long.

Is there anyway to automate this process?

Comment: Have you considered using an averaging convolution operation?

Comment: I was more thinking something that could find the point rather than change the actual data to find it?

Comment: I don't think that's really possible. You're claiming you want to determine a specific gradient change of the underlying process, but, presumably, you're admitting that there's noise whose gradient exceeds the threshold you may consider for determination of that point. If the noise is of much higher frequency than the change in underlying gradient, it's a simple matter to design a filter which will suppress that noise without changing the timing (phase) of the underlying process. If the noise is within the gradient change's bandwidth you've got a bigger issue on your hands.

Comment: I've decided to go about this a different way so my question changes now. If you could have a look at the edited question to see if you have an answer for the new problem, that would be helpful. But thankyou I understand the problem your posing.

Comment: The final solution is going to depend on how accurate you need that specific point estimated. If you can live with +/- 10 steps from that desired point then I think it might be quickest to just run a windowing function that computes the variance of the next N points. If the variance is below some threshold then mark the starting point of the current window and maybe keep sliding the window to make sure the variance settles. But given that the noise has very high frequency you might simply consider marking the point at which a HPF outputs low enough values. Or some combination of these two.